# Can I force Flash use for MP4 playback?

Tags: video.js

I want to abandon the HTML5 video tag for a 8MB MP4 file I want to play on a webpage because it has been doing strange things on Chrome on Windows 7/8 but not on Chrome <=Vista. Strange as in:

- Not loading it sometimes
- Most of the time but not always vertically squashing the video content 70%
- Flickering wildly

This has been duplicated on a number of different machines we have tested on.

Is there some markup I could use to force an MP4 to be played by Flash only?

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 5):

You can make the player use Flash using the `techOrder` parameter.

```
<video ... data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash"]}' ... />
```

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/tech.md

Comment: This did not work for me, as the JS still tries to load the HTML5 player in Firefox 20.

Comment: @TravisWebb use above solution to edit the video.js. It worked 100% for me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give the priprity to flash player first go to the video.js or video.min.js file and replace the ["HTML5"],["flash"] with ["flash"],["HTML5"]

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
 vjs.options = {

      // Default order of fallback technology
      'techOrder': ['html5','flash'],
```

with

```
vjs.options = {

      // Default order of fallback technology
      'techOrder': ['flash','html5'],
```

in `video.js`. The script will now give `flash` the priority to run, rather then html5